# What happen when we don't close `ChannelHandlerContext` in Netty?

Tags: netty

I see in the `exceptionCaught` in [Netty example](https://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html), it call `ctx.close()` which will eventually close the `Channel`. I'm curious that what happen if we don't close the context here, will it be a leak? Or Netty will close the `Channel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on where the exception is thrown from that bubbles up here. Also depending on the exception you may not want to close the context (And so the connection). It all depends really on the protocol / channel type etc. If the exception is thrown because of an IO error netty usually close the channel by itself. That said its a good idea to handle things explicit if you think the error is "non-recoverable".

Comment: i agree to the point that handling exception likely depends on the specific case. Just want to know what the good practice to not leaking connection/socket fd when handle netty exception.

"If the exception is thrown because of an IO error netty usually close the channel by itself" --> 

do you have reference for this? Netty doc mainly just say: normally we should close the ctx , but not specific about when we can just ignore it

Comment: it's an implementation detail in `AbstractChannel`. So for a rule of thumb if you think you can't recover close the channel.

Comment: "by closing the channel" you meant close the channel context, right? What i try to understand here is that: if in `exceptionCaught` method (of the last handler), we don't close the context, will Netty close it or it will keep connection open (a connection leak)?

Comment: You should close it if you can't recover from the error... And just to be clear calling close on the context will at the end close the channel.

Comment: :) thanks for the replies. but i think it still does not answer the main question: what happen if i don't close it?

Comment: any reference regarding this "If the exception is thrown because of an IO error netty usually close the channel by itself."